# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (MAC)

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error, discord.js

I keep getting a `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` when running my code. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'help') {
    msg.reply('I dont want to help you now! go ask somebody else!');
}

bot.user.setStatus('available')
  bot.user.setPresence({
      game: {
          name: Made by sorryIwonbtwYT for TheSinni',
          type: "WATCHING",
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please always add the language tag

Comment: What is `bot` defined as?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a ' near your setPresence

This should fix your code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: 'Made by sorryIwonbtwYT for TheSinni', type: 'WATCHING' }, status: 'online'  })       
})

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'help') {
    msg.reply('I dont want to help you now! go ask somebody else!');
}
});

client.login('YOUR_TOKEN')
```